# Can acetate sheets be put in the oven?

Tags: baking

I have tried lining mini cheesecake pan (with removable bottoms)in parchment paper, as I do with larger cheesecakes. The parchment paper bends in the mini version. Can I use food-grade acetate in place of the parchment?

Comment: I *think* it will melt. I could be wrong, but until you know for certain, be cautious

Comment: You should only post a question once, and you have this one here also:  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/96239/parchment-substitute.  Delete one of the two?

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate of June's other question.

Answer (score 1):

Acetate sheets or strips [should not be heated](http://blog.bakedeco.com/2017/07/31/can-you-put-acetate-strip-in-the-oven/), so do not use them to line a pan that will be put into the oven.